# How to write logout function in functional component using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in creating functional components, in Class Components we declare logout function in this

```
logout = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("userToken", '');
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ redirect: true });


}
```

format but i don't know how to declare variable and how to write push to another functional component.

Can anyone please help me in this query?

Comment: "push to another functional component" means routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router v4 has now added the useHistory hook for stateless / functional components. Sample snippet that would handle logout in your case

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Logout() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleLogOut() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("userToken", '');
    sessionStorage.clear();
    history.push("/sigin"); // whichever component you want it to route to
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleLogOut}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer provided by @sv12, you can also use history module.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```